# Flash text effect on image

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem is that when I MouseHover over the image works fine but if I mouseover on the title, this have flashes. Example: http://www.adminvps.com.ar/trabajos/sofi_v/pintura.html

Mi code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.item a img').hover(function () {
     id = '.' + $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: .2
        }, 200);
        $(id).removeClass('hide');
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500);
        $('.text').addClass('hide');
    });
});
```

```css
.text {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.text span {
    color: #808080;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
 <div class="id1 text hide">Title <br /> texto</div>
 <a href="#"><img id="id1" src="http://www.adminvps.com.ar/trabajos/sofi_v/example.jpg" alt="" style="max-width: 500px;" /></a>
</div>
<br />
<div class="item">
 <div class="id2 text hide">Title <br /> texto</div>
 <a href="#"><img id="id2" src="http://www.adminvps.com.ar/trabajos/sofi_v/example.jpg" alt="" style="max-width: 500px;" /></a>
</div>
```

Any idea how to remove the flash?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can also be achieved by using [CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) (pure CSS, no JS)

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxhx7o0q/1/) I just wrote from your code with a working example.

And these are the lines added to it:

```
.item img {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    opacity: 1;
}

.item:hover img {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms;
    transition: opacity 200ms;
}

.item:hover .hide {
    display: block;
}
```

I had to point at the img instead of the whole div (`.item`) because the text was getting less opacity too.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

When your mouse goes from the `img` tag to the `div` tag it triggers the mouseout event (the second function you have in the hover).

You can check inside this function if the new element is that specific div - and if so just do nothing.

This code will do the trick:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.item a img').hover(function (e) {
        id = '.' + $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: .2
        }, 200);
        $(id).removeClass('hide');
    }, function (e) {
        if (e.toElement == $(this).parents('.item').find('div')[0]) {
            return;
        }
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500);
        $('.text').addClass('hide');
    });
    $('.item div').hover(function(e) {
        return false;
    }, function(e) {
        return false;
    });
});
```

Notice I added the `e` variable (it's the Event var) to the function so I can use it inside.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the title is outside the image where you're setting the event.

One solution would be to place the title div inside the a element and assign the event to the a's hover instead of the img, like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="id1 text hide">Title <br /> texto</div>
        <img id="id1" src="http://www.adminvps.com.ar/trabajos/sofi_v/example.jpg" alt="" style="max-width: 500px;" />
    </a>
</div>
```

And

```
$('.item a')
```

Instead of

```
$('.item a img')
```

Also the a element should have at least the same width and height as the img element, so the event is triggered properly. This can be easily accomplished by making it display as a block:

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

Hope it helps.